# Can I use Google Places API to collect lat/lng coordinates of street intersections?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am searching for the way to identify lat/lng coordinates of street intersections of, for example, city blocks in specified area. Previously, I tried to utilize the data from OpenStreetMap to do this, but it is not working well. (Please refer to my previous question: "[How can I exhaustively collect latlng coordinates of street intersections from OpenStreetMap (or from any other data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033993/how-can-i-exhaustively-collect-latlng-coordinates-of-street-intersections)")

I was searching for the alternative method, and I found that Google Places API seems to offer the data I want. In the following page ([link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)), Google says that it supports the Place Type "intersection". I tried the following url to access their API (with replacing MY_API_KEY with my Google API key),

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=38.8962391,-77.0280818&radius=1000&types=intersection&sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY

but no luck, it returned

> {
>       "debug_info" : [],
>       "html_attributions" : [],
>       "results" : [],
>       "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
>    }

I was wondering why this is not working. Is it because I am in the area that the service is not supported (the area I specified above is in Washington D.C.), or am I making some mistake in the query? Is there any walk around to this or do you know better way to find the street intersection coordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676790/getting-an-intersection-with-google-places-geocoding-api

Comment: Hi zeantsoi, Thank you for your comment. I see, so we cannot collect intersections by simply using Google Places API... Thank you.