# Geo-coding for intersection street using Python

Tags: python, api, dictionary, geocoding, geopy

Does anyone know how to get **latitude** and **longitude** of an intersection of 2 roads given 2 roads address by and Map API like Google map API?

I currently find a solution for Python such as from `geopy`.

Thank you!

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676790/getting-an-intersection-with-google-places-geocoding-api ?

Answer (score -1):

```
def loc(streetA, streetB):
    res = requests.get('https://www.google.com/maps/place/'+streetA+' & '+streetB)
    return re.findall(r'll=(.*?)" item', res.text)[0].split(',')

gps = loc('19th rd nw', 'kafir rd')
print(gps)
>>['38.302811', '-95.767682']
```

Its not an api but you can always just scrape google maps? Here is a function I threw together that takes two strings representing the roads that intersect.